# generate dynamic array inside array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I am using Laravel .if i `dd()` `$arrBody I` get following result dd($arrBody);

```
    array:7[▼
            "first_name" => "john"
            "last_name" => "doe"
            "email_address" => "john@gmail.com",
            "age"=> 25,
            "date"=>"2021-07-9",
            "country"=>"USA",
            "code"=>"3045"
]
```

Now I want to get email,firstname and last name from $arryBody and assigned them to email,first_name and last_name key. But rest of keys like age, country,state and date i want them to go in custom_fields array but its like a hardcoded here. since I am displaying age, date,country one by one. My array may have more key/values so I want to make custom_fields array dynamic. I want field_name inside inside custom_fields to have a same name that comes after email,first_name and last_name of $arrBody array instead of manually writing field_name and want to assign that keys value to "value"

```
$data = [
        "subscribers"=>[
            [
                "email"=> $arrBody['email'],
                "first_name"=> $arrBody['first_name'],
                "last_name"=> $arrBody['last_name'],
                "subscribed"=> true,
                
                "custom_fields"=>[
                    [ 
                        "field_name"=> "age",
                        "value_type"=> "text",
                        "value"=> array_key_exists('age',$arrBody) ? $arrBody['age']:''
                    ],
                    [ 
                        "field_name"=> "country",
                        "value_type"=> "text",
                        "value"=> array_key_exists('country',$arrBody) ? $arrBody['country']:''
                    ],
                    [ 
                        "field_name"=> "date",
                        "value_type"=> "text",
                        "value"=> array_key_exists('date',$arrBody) ? $arrBody['date']:''
                    ],
                    //so on...
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];
```

In Laravel I can use

```
$main = ['email', 'first_name', 'last_name'];

$subscriber = Arr::only($arrBody, $main);

$custom = Arr::exclude($arrBody, $main);
```

Now I want this $custom array inside  "custom_fields"=>[] dynamically until the length of $custom array instead of checking if it has age, country etc or not.
something like this if possible

```
custom_fields" => [
                        [
                            "field_name" => array_keys($custom)
                            "value_type" => "text",
                            "value" => array_values($custom)
                        ],
            //go until the end of $custom array
];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = [
    "subscribers"=>[
        [
            "email"=> $arrBody['email'],
            "first_name"=> $arrBody['first_name'],
            "last_name"=> $arrBody['last_name'],
            "subscribed"=> true,
            "custom_fields"=> collect($custom)->map(function($value, $key) {
                return [ 
                    'field_name' => $key,
                    'value_type' => gettype($value),
                    'value' => $value,
                ]; 
            }),
        ]
    ]
];
```

add `->toArray()` after if you want it back to an array over a collection,

Also gettype wont work unless you actually use those types, not a number in a string format.

Comment: thanks, do I need to do  ->toArray(), I want array of data inside custom_fields=>[]

Comment: Give it a go and find out.